# How to send Eclipse console view to another workspace in Windows 10?

Tags: eclipse, windows

It's been an hour and I couldn't find a solution for this. What I'm trying to accomplish here is using Eclipse on a laptop efficiently utilizing Windows 10's virtual desktops.

Problem is, even when I drag and drop the Console view to make it "float" it's just a floating window and not a standalone window thus it does not have a separate taskbar icon. This means that I cannot send it to another Windows 10 workspace, but if I do the entire Eclipse workspace is being moved. This drives me crazy, with IntelliJ it's a snap, but I want to do it with Eclipse Mars.

I have tried the Window/New window in Eclipse, but since it's a different workspace when I run my code on *window A* it does not get presented on *window B*'s console view.

The idea is to switch between the code editor and console view by pressing Ctrl + Win + Left/Right.

Appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Close every view except the package explorer and the editor. Click on the window menu and open a new window. In this window, open every view you want. Then drag this window to the other virtual desktop.